# Calling External Command On Python Without Quotes

Tags: python, linux, shell, call, subprocess

Following the advice given in;
[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python)

I have been experimenting using the call() function to call an external command, however the command I need to call is being called correctly but it does not like the parameters being passed to it.
This is because the Call function is passing the parameters with ' 's around them.

E.g

```
test = call(['/opt/program/something/lookup', 'search "bob"'])
```

The search part must be passed to the command lookup without any characters surrounding it, I have tried a few different permutations of the call function with varying levels of quotes, spaces, lack of commas etc. The second statement - bob, must be within quotes.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Example of return value of test atm;

```
Error: 'search "bob"' is not a valid command.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work - if not then please **update** the question with specific error text:

```
test = call(['/opt/program/something/lookup', 'search', '"bob"'])
```